# Curl to C# .Net WebApi POST call

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, curl, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I need to change the following curl api call to C# / .NET

curl -X POST http://jasserver:8010/jderest/file/upload --form file="@C:\temp\test.pdf;type=application/pdf" --form moAdd="@C:\temp\upload.json;type=application/json"

I've tried using Postman, when I execute the API it works, but the Curl and C# code created by Postman do not work.  I am getting 500 error.
The curl code above (not created by Postman) works, but I cannot get the C# code to work.

This is the code genarated by Postman. It does return 500 error.

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://webserver.domain.com:8010/jderest/file/upload");
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        content.Add(new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(@"C:\temp\test.pdf")), "file", @"C:\temp\test.pdf");
        content.Add(new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(@"C:\temp\upload.json")), "moAdd", @"C:\temp\upload.json");
        request.Content = content;
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Comment: Could you please include your C# request code snippet? What exactly got faild?

Comment: You would require to use multipartformDataContent attribute while calling your API.

Comment: I have also tested with the console app, you can check the updated answer. To narrow down the issuee, you could create a sample api and send request  from your console app. If hit your controller successfully, then contact your API devs because you should know API defination.

Answer (score -1):

> The curl code above (not created by Postman) works, but I cannot get
> the C# code to work.

Actually, it would be nicer if you would could include your snippet within your question. However, getting 500 error code might have numerous reasons but the more common is the request format. If your request is in incorrect format it will always ended up with 500 status code.

Therefore, while you would request files along with class object or only files you would require to use [MultipartFormDataContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.multipartformdatacontent?view=net-7.0) because we cannot send files or byte data using json content.

Thus, you could try collosing way:

**Upate: Using Console App**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;


//Rigion Call API from console
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{

    var requestMode = new HttpClientReqeustModel();

    requestMode.MyByteData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\YourFileName.pdf");
    requestMode.FilePath = @"D:\YourFileName.pdf";
    requestMode.FileName = "YourFileName.pdf";

    //Create Multipart Request
    var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    formContent.Add(new StringContent(requestMode.FilePath), "FilePath");
    formContent.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(requestMode.MyByteData)), "MyByteData", requestMode.FileName);

    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:5094/UploadFiles", formContent);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"API Response Code: {response.StatusCode}");
        Console.WriteLine("Data posted successfully");
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

**Using Asp.net core MVC**

Request Model:

```
 public class HttpClientReqeustModel
    {
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public byte[] MyByteData { get; set; }
    }
```

**Note:** You can use  [IFormFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-7.0)  if you would send request from asp.net core MVC app but for windows from or WPF app you can keep as [byte[]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/byte-data-type).

Asp.net Core Request Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SendFileRequestAPIControllre()
        {
            
            HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
           

            //Bind Request Model

            var requestMode = new HttpClientReqeustModel();

            requestMode.MyByteData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\YourFileName.pdf");
            requestMode.FilePath = @"D:\YourFileName.pdf";
            requestMode.FileName = "YourFilename.pdf";

            //Create Multipart Request
            var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            formContent.Add(new StringContent(requestMode.FilePath), "FilePath");
            formContent.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(requestMode.MyByteData)), "MyByteData", requestMode.FileName);

            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:5094/UploadFiles", formContent);

            return Ok();
        }
```

API Reqeust Model:

```
public class APIRequestModel
    {
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        public IFormFile MyByteData { get; set; }
    }
```

API Controller:

```
        [Route("UploadFiles")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> PostComplexTypeData([FromForm] APIRequestModel requestModel)
        {
            try
            {
                var path = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "WordAutomation/", requestModel.MyByteData.FileName);


                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await requestModel.MyByteData.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    stream.Close();
                }
               
                return StatusCode(200);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"Error. msg: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on it you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.multipartcontent?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Thank You for your help.  I am using a Console application.  The solution you offered is getting the 500 error. But the curl code still works. I don't have access to the server, so I don't know what is causing the 500 error. I don't know why curl works and .NET does not.

Comment: this curl also works curl -X POST http://webps11.vanhoof.com:8010/jderest/file/upload --form file="@C:\temp\test.pdf;type=application/json" --form moAdd="@C:\temp\upload.json;type=application/json".  Also I noticed your example uploads 1 file, the curl code uploads 2 files. One Pdf and one Json. And I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Make sure property names are passed correctltly, additionally, is there any way I can reproduce your issue? Importantly, need to know your API defination what argument it takes.

Comment: In addition, please include your code snippet how you are sending request from console app.

Comment: I did update my question with the snippet code.  This is the upload.json file. {
    "username": "userid",
    "password": "password",
    "deviceName":"MyComputer",
    "ssoEnabled":false,
    "moStructure":"BTR411S",
    "moKey":[
        "00011|RV|144876|001"
    ],
   "formName":"P0311_W0421A",
    "version":"WSI0011",
    "file":{
        "filename":"test.pdf",
        "fileLocation":"C:\\temp\\test.pdf",
        "itemName":"Uploaded File APIs",
        "sequence":0
    }
}

Comment: I think the issue is sending 2 files at the same time and specifying the type.  I don't know how to do that in .NET.  The API Endpoint is expecting two files.